# How to go to the next value of a While loop

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a `While loop` that reads a `line` of a `file.txt`. I also have a method named `VerifyPhoto` that returns `true/false` I want to go to next item of the `while loop` if the returned value is `false`. How Could I do that ? I tried `break` and `return` but it just leave all and back to the `form`...

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
  {
     if(VerifyPhoto(filed.matriculation) == false)
        {
          //go to the next line of the file.txt
        }
  }
```

Comment: `break` to leave the current loop, `return` to leave the method entirely, `continue` to skip the current iteration and go to the next. I guess you're looking for `continue`

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it now, since `break`, `return` and `continue` are all related to this: `goto`. All of these keywords are so-called **jumps**. However, `goto` is old and considered bad practice, because code using `goto` are very difficult to follow. The 3 former keywords are basically all `goto`, but they are at least a lot easier to follow. Btw. I still remember the time I had to work with a language that did not implement any of those, so I had to juggle with `bool`s. It was horror to implement, and horror to debug...

Comment: I remeber `goto` when I was working with `C` haha! My professor called it `Spaghetti programming` '-' . Really thanks, I didn't know the difference between the `jumps`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to get familiar with other control statement: [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[EDIT] Newest version of the doc: [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx), thanks Jeppe.

Comment: It will ignore all the rest inside the while and go to the next iteration ?

Comment: @Ghaleon Yes, it will, just like in the example given. :) When you use `continue`, it will literally continue to the next iteration, just like `break` breaks out of the loop.

Comment: [Newest version of MSDN `continue` doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`continue;` (some more to make it 30 chars)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual code, maybe you could simply invert the boolean test, so you do something only if `VerifyPhoto` returns `true`:

```
while (...)
{
    if(VerifyPhoto(filed.matriculation))
    {
        // Do the job
    }
}
```

Comment: But one thing i'll verify is if there's an item on a `CheckedListBox` having it or not i'll do the job, but I have these other test ;s Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing iteration statement in which it appears

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    if(VerifyPhoto(filed.matriculation) == false)
    {
        continue;
        //go to the next line of the file.txt
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something in the way you are doing this?
Do you read the first line before starting the loop?
if so don't you need something like

```
**string line;**
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
  {
     if(VerifyPhoto(filed.matriculation) == false)
        {
          //go to the next line of the file.txt
          **line = file.ReadLine();**
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read line by line then [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) may be useful.

Also what you're looking for is the [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1(v=vs.80).aspx) statement.

```
string myFile = @"c:\path\to\my\file.txt";

foreach(string line in File.ReadLines(myFile))
{
    //Do stuff
    //if(!VerifyPhoto())
    //    continue;
    //Do other logic
}
```